# Nginx rewrite to fixed destination link

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I would like to rewrite all incoming links to a fixed destination link.
Any arguments and URI paths should be dropped, so

http://domain1.com/blah/blah.html?test=3&test2=4

should always become

http://newdomain.com/index.php

It seems so trivial but I don't seem to get it - I always end up with at least the URI path being taken over.

Comment: Do you want to actually redirect the user?

Comment: Yes, redirect it is.